# Generate a random, fixed length BigInteger in Java

Tags: java, random, biginteger

I am attempting to generate a random 20 digit `BigInteger` in Java.

So far, I have been able to generate a fixed length hex value.

```
    // generate a user-specified number of random bytes
    public void getRandomNumber(int count) {

        byte[] bytes = new byte[count];
        new SecureRandom().nextBytes(bytes);
        String random = new String(Hex.encode(bytes));
        System.out.println(random);
    }
```

This is ideal for a fixed length hex generation. But I struggle to find an efficient method of doing this for a decimal representation; when converting from hex to `BigInteger(hexValue, 16)`, the length will vary.

I have considered trying this by setting upper and lower bounds, or by generating something *big enough* and trimming to the desired length, but those methods do not feel very clean.

**Edit: The solution I have came up with that is working fine in my program:**

```
// generate a random number with specified bit length
    public void getTokenID() {
        int count = 64;
        SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
        BigInteger randomCountLength;
        String token;

        do {
            randomCountLength = new BigInteger(count, rnd);
            token = randomCountLength.toString();
        } while (token.length() != 20);

        Tid = token;
    }
```

Comment: When you say 20 digit, do you mean decimal, hex or binary digits?

Comment: @ArtjomB. Sorry, I meant decimal digits. I think I have found the solution to my problem - although maybe it is not the most efficient solution I will add it to my post.

Comment: @lb-99 it's better to post a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) than edit your answer into the post. This keeps things clear and separate and lets people vote on the answer along with all the others--it may not be the best solution. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen for some reason I do not get the option to answer this question - potentially as it has been marked as duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

What I understand that your problem is to generate random number with fixed length (fixed number of digits)

It is obvious that using hex value will work since any hex digit represent 4 bytes. So when you fix the length of bytes (bytes table in your code) it work fine

What I advice you when dealing with decimal number is :

1- There is methods for generating random number with lower and upper bound, for example Random betwen 5 and 10, so if you want for example a random number with 20 digits , you have to generate random number between (10^19) and (10^20-1)

2- The second is hardcoded method to make a loop of 20 iterations when you generate random digit (between 0 and 9 exept the the digit of strong weight which must be between 1 and 9) and you get the number.